# Angular 4 - Create Heat Chart

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, heatmap

I need to create heat chart like this (Image Below).

I searched most of the blogs and google for this.

[image: Heat chart]

I've searched following libraries with no help to find.

https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas

But these are diffrent heat charts than I needed.

Comment: SO is not focusing on questions that ask for library recommendation(s)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? @sangwin gawande

Comment: No..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highcharts the data is assigned for a particular area. On your map the data is independent from formal map areas (there's no single value for every the state/county). So creating that kind of map would be quite difficult (in my opinion).

**Example of how it works in Highcharts:**

Official demo of a map with `colorAxis` (http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis) that can be used for visualizing the temperature: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/geojson/